# Extracting data between two tags in HTML file

Tags: html, xml, matlab, extract, large-files

I've got a HUUUGE HTML file here saved on my system, which contains data from a product catalogue. The data is structured such that for each product record the name is  between two tags  (name) and (/name) .

Each product has up to 3 attributes: name, productID, and color, but not all products will have all these attributes.

How would I go about extracting this data for each product without mixing up the product attributes? The file is also 50 megabyte!

Code example ....

```
<name>'hat'</name>
blah blah blah
<prodId>'1829493'</prodId>
blah blah blah
<color>'cyan'</color>

blah blah 
blah blah blah
blah blah blah

<name>'shirt'</name>
blah blah blahblah blah blah
<prodId>'193'</prodId>

<name>'dress'</name>
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
<prodId>'18'</prodId>
<color>'dark purple'</color>
```

Comment: Post some code. If the input data is sufficiently well-formed, perhaps there's a simple answer.

Comment: Looks like reading an xml document. You can try to slightly alter the function provided as an example in the xmlread help page (http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/xmlread.html).

Comment: @Kerrek SB 
I've added an example 'nugget' of code.

Comment: @Bob: Hmm, in this restricted case, and if you promise that the format is exactly as in the example, you could probably get away with a regular expression to extract the three fields. Something like `sed` or `awk` should let you write a single command to transform the data into whatever format you require.

Comment: Thanks guys. So if I wanted to find all the names in the file I would use regexp to locate all the occurrences of  name and /name, and extract the bits in between?

Comment: Are the name/prodId/color tags contained inside another element, `<item>`, say?

Comment: I agree with RichieCotton, is this a properly structured XML file, or simply a bunch of text with some embedded `<tag>...</tag>` syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file of size 50 MB isn't so big that you can't just load its contents directly into MATLAB as a string, which you can do with the function [FILEREAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fileread.html):

```
strContents = fileread('yourfile.html');
```

Assuming the file format you have above, you can then parse the contents with the function [REGEXP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html) (using [named token capture](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html#bqm94nz-1)):

```
expr = '<(?<tag>name|prodId|color)>''([^<>]+)''</\k<tag>>';
tokens = regexp(strContents,expr,'tokens');
tokens = vertcat(tokens{:});
```

And the contents of `token` using your sample file contents will be:

```
tokens = 

    'name'      'hat'        
    'prodId'    '1829493'    
    'color'     'cyan'       
    'name'      'shirt'      
    'prodId'    '193'        
    'name'      'dress'      
    'prodId'    '18'         
    'color'     'dark purple'
```

You may then want to parse the resulting N-by-2 cell array and place the contents in a [structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html) with fields `'name'`, `'prodId'`, and `'color'`. The difficulty is that not every entry will have all three fields. Assuming each `'name'` will be followed by either a `'prodId'`, a `'color'`, or *both* (in the order `'prodId'` *then* `'color'`), then the following code should work for you:

```
s = struct('name',[],'prodId',[],'color',[]);  %# Initialize structure
nTokens = size(tokens,1);                      %# Get number of tokens
nameIndex = find(strcmp(tokens(:,1),'name'));  %# Find indices of 'name'
[s(1:numel(nameIndex)).name] = deal(tokens{nameIndex,2});  %# Fill 'name' field

%# Find and fill 'prodId' that follows a 'name':
index = strcmp(tokens(min(nameIndex+1,nTokens),1),'prodId');
[s(index).prodId] = deal(tokens{nameIndex(index)+1,2});

%# Find and fill 'color' that follows a 'name':
index = strcmp(tokens(min(nameIndex+1,nTokens),1),'color');
[s(index).color] = deal(tokens{nameIndex(index)+1,2});

%# Find and fill 'color' that follows a 'prodId':
index = strcmp(tokens(min(nameIndex+2,nTokens),1),'color');
[s(index).color] = deal(tokens{min(nameIndex(index)+2,nTokens),2});
```

And the contents of `s` using your sample file contents will be:

```
>> s(1)

      name: 'hat'
    prodId: '1829493'
     color: 'cyan'

>> s(2)

      name: 'shirt'
    prodId: '193'
     color: []

>> s(3)

      name: 'dress'
    prodId: '18'
     color: 'dark purple'
```

Comment: +1 nice use of regexps, although it reminds me of this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @Amro: What can I say, I like to live dangerously. ;)

Comment: That's a fantastic solution - exactly what I was after. However, my example of "tags" are an abstraction of the truth. Would it be possible for the code to be more flexible what the tag pairs are. 

Could the pair of tags, be two  strings? With the pair's of tags stored in an structure? In the above code, we assume the second of the tag pair is the previous with a '/' in it.

Rather than <name> & </name>, it might be <name> and <endofname>

Comment: @Bob M.: That is easy enough to account for. If the format is `<XXX>` and `<endofXXX>`, just make the last part of the match expression `<endof\k<tag>>`. If you could have either `</XXX>` or `<endofXXX>` as the second tag, then use this for the last part of the match expression: `<(?:/|endof)\k<tag>>`

Comment: @gnovice : Thanks again. What I'm getting at is what about if the first tag is <name> and the other is <randomlookingtag> ? ... My tags aren't as 'nicely' defined as I would like in some cases.

Comment: @Bob M.: If your second tag is just any string contained inside `<>`, then you can use this for your match expression: `'<(name|prodId|color)>''([^<>]+)''<([^<>]+)>'`. This will also capture the second tag as an additional token.

Comment: @gnovice : that would work, but some of my data inside the tag pairs is HTML and because of this there maybe the odd <br> inside the data which would mess up your solution. Let's say I know there could be <br> and <c> in the text, how do we ignore them so your solution works...

`blah <name>'My <c>wonderfully <br> awkward string :)'<randomlookingtag> blah blah`

Comment: @Bob M.: This is why you need to give a good, complete example of your data **in your question**, so that you avoid a long series of comments like this. If there are any more requirements to add, please put them in your question where they belong. At any rate, you can handle extra strings like `<br>` and `<c>` by first removing them from your string before applying your regex, like so: `strContents = regexprep(strContents,{'<c>','<br>'},'');`

Comment: My apologies, I've never used this website before. Once again I give my thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of solving this sort of problem: string manipulation with regexes (as suggested by gnovice) or parsing the file (or a mix of the two).  Parsing is often best if your file is very well structured; regexes win for messy files.

Here's the parsing solution.

Start by downloading [xmliotools](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12907-xmliotools), and calling `xml_read` on your file.  Your example isn't completely  reproducible, so here are two different versions of the data.

Save this to `test1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<name>'hat'</name>
<prodId>'1829493'</prodId>
<color>'cyan'</color>
<name>'dress'</name>
<prodId>'18'</prodId>
<color>'dark purple'</color>
</root>
```

Save this to `test2.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>'hat'</name>
<prodId>'1829493'</prodId>
<color>'cyan'</color>
</item>
<item>
<name>'dress'</name>
<prodId>'18'</prodId>
<color>'dark purple'</color>
</item>
</root>
```

Now compare

```
x1 = xml_read('test1.xml')
x2 = xml_read('test2.xml')
```

Comment: Thanks Richie, I'm going to try both methods, and see how the speed compares.