# extracting data from within xml files using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am a complete programming beginner trying to learn MATLAB.  I want to extract numerical data from a bunch of different xml files.  The numerical data items are bounded by the tags  and .  How do I write a program in MATLAB?

My algorithm:

```
1. Open the folder
2. Look into each of 50 xml files, one at a time
3. Where the tag <HNB.1></HNB.1> exists, copy numerical contents between said tag and write results into a new file
4. The new file name given for step 3 should be the same as the initial file name read in Step 2, being appended with "_data extracted"
```

example:

```
FileName = Stewart.xml
Contents = blah blah blah <HNB.1>2</HNB.1> blah blah
NewFileName = Stewart_data extracted.txt
Contents = 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582250/extracting-data-between-two-tags-in-html-file-matlab

Answer (score 8):

The fundamental function in MATLAB to read xml data is [xmlread](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/xmlread.html); but if you're a complete beginner, it can be tricky to work with just that. Try [this series of blog postings](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2010/11/01/xml-and-matlab-navigating-a-tree/) that show you how to put it all together.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to read this file:

```html
<PositiveSamples numImages="14">
<image numSubRegions="2" filename="TestingScene.jpg">
 <subregion yStart="213" yEnd="683" xStart="1" xEnd="236"/>
 <subregion yStart="196" yEnd="518" xStart="65" xEnd="226"/>
</image>
</PositiveSamples>
```

Then in matlab, read the file contents as follows:

```
%read xml file
xmlDoc = xmlread('PositiveSamples.xml');

%Get root element
root = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();

%Read attributevale
numOfImages = root.getAttribute('numImages');
numOfImages = char(numOfImages);   
numOfImages = uint16(eval(numOfImages));
```