# Binary SVM Cascade Classifier Matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, classification, svm, training-data

I am trying to train a SVM with data that I have extracted from movie scenes. This data comes in .xml files and contains information about both audio and video of the scene. Now I am having problems in finding how to train a SVM in Matlab. First of all it is not clear how to get the data from the files that I have generated and get them to be correctly operated by Matlab.

Just to give more info, the classification has to be in cascade because I have got 4 movie genres. I have been looking in posts here and in the Mathworks page and I couldn´t figure this out. So my question is:

How can I get the data from my .xml files and train them with a SVM using Matlab?

This is an example of an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPEG-7:ACCION>
<CSD_values>
    0
    0
</CSD_values>
<SCD_values>
    11
    191
</SCD_values>
<EHD_values>
    2
    7
</EHD_values>
</MPEG-7:ACCION>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions at once: 1) Reading xml file 2) classifying with SVM. Please provide all essential information, i.e. what is the format of your xml file? See [ask].

Comment: Sorry, it is my first time asking here. The xml file format is like this:

Comment: If you don't know how to read xml files in matlab, you may look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706980/extracting-data-from-within-xml-files-using-matlab