# Using MATLAB to parse HTML for URL in anchors, help fast

Tags: html, regex, matlab, anchor

I'm on a strict time limit and I really need a regex to parse this type of anchor (they're all in this format)

`<a href="20120620_0512_c2_1024.jpg">20120620_0512_c2_102..&gt;</a>`

for the URL

`20120620_0512_c2_1024.jpg`

I know its not a full URL, it's relative, please help

Here's my code so far

```
year = datestr(now,'yyyy');
timestamp = datestr(now,'yyyymmdd');
html = urlread(['http://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov//data/REPROCESSING/Completed/' year '/c2/' timestamp '/']);
links = regexprep(html, '<a href=.*?>', '');
```

Comment: what is the result you have gotten so far with your code? Could you show it and the code? :)

Comment: it's best to edit it in your question. :) put 4 spaces before it and it gets put in  code block

Comment: Do you really need to use Matlab? Usually I would consider using some scripting language like Python or Ruby - they have much better facilities for HTML parsing.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582250/extracting-data-between-two-tags-in-html-file-matlab

Comment: Yes, this is a project for school and it needs to be done entirely in Matlab

Comment: @jsalonen that regex expression doesn't really work in this case because I need to get the URL from inside the quotes, not what's inside the tag which is what that question is asking to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
url = 'http://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/data/REPROCESSING/Completed/2012/c2/20120620/';
html = urlread(url);
t = regexp(html, '<a href="([^"]*\.jpg)">', 'tokens');
t = [t{:}]'
```

The resulting cell array (truncated):

```
t = 
    '20120620_0512_c2_1024.jpg'
    '20120620_0512_c2_512.jpg'
    ...
    '20120620_2200_c2_1024.jpg'
    '20120620_2200_c2_512.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
htmlLink = '<a href="20120620_0512_c2_1024.jpg">20120620_0512_c2_102..&gt;</a>';

link = regexprep(htmlLink, '(<a href=")(.*\.jpg)(">.*</a>)', '$2');

link =
20120620_0512_c2_1024.jpg
```

`regexprep` works also for cell arrays of strings, so this works too:

```
htmlLinksCellArray = { '<a href="20120620_0512_c2_1024.jpg">20120620_0512_c2_102..&gt;</a>', '<a href="20120620_0512_c2_1025.jpg">20120620_0512_c2_102..&gt;</a>', '<a href="20120620_0512_c2_1026.jpg">20120620_0512_c2_102..&gt;</a>' };

linksCellArray = regexprep(htmlLinksCellArray, '(<a href=")(.*\.jpg)(">.*</a>)', '$2')

linksCellArray = 
'20120620_0512_c2_1024.jpg'  '20120620_0512_c2_1025.jpg'  '20120620_0512_c2_1026.jpg'
```

Comment: This regex only works on that one html snippet, I need it to be able to parse the html of this page [link](http://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov//data/REPROCESSING/Completed/2012/c2/20120620/)

Comment: But I really like that your regex includes the .jpg ending, that will simplify my code a bit. But I would like to be able to parse the entire pages html instead of parsing an array of anchors from the page